# Finding the constant k from density function

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

Wondering how to find the value of the constant k for this. I know you have to integrate, so I integrated both functions, however I'm not quite sure on the steps afterwards. Any help would be greatly appreciated![image: 1]]

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^1 kx^2~ dx+\int_1^2 k(2-x)~ dx=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the integral over the density function must be equal to $1$.

That is:

$$\int_0^1 kx^2~ dx+\int_1^2 k(2-x)~ dx=1$$

Computing the two integrals gives:$$\frac{k}{2}+\frac{k}{3}=1 \iff \frac{5k}{6}=1$$ and so we have $$k=\frac{6}{5}$$

Comment: Ah yes, I was equating then to 1 separately for some reason, thank you;

Comment: No problem mate :)